# How to reuse python code in one file from a different file

Tags: python

My question is very simple. I have a piece of code that I want to reuse, but I don't want to copy it every time I use it. Is there any way I can import it and run it in my main file?

For example, in file `code1.py`:

```
a=1
```

I want to run in `code2.py`:

```
import code1
b=a+1
print(b)
```

The output says `a` is not defined. I don't know where I got it wrong. I am a beginner in Python, so this will help me a lot in the future, thanks.

Comment: `from code1 import a` would do it.

Comment: if you do `import code1` like you have then you will need to access it like `b = code1.a + 1` ... otherwise do `from code1 import a` to use `a` directly in code2.py

Comment: Note that `from code1 import a` won't see any future changes to `code1.a`, so you should only do it if `a` is constant.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure that the two files are in the same directory.

If this is the case, you can directly import

```
from filename import variablename/class/function
```

in your case:

```
from code1 import a
```

Answer (score 0):

This lesson is good to understand imports in python: https://realpython.com/python-import/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import the variable from the your Python module to use it.

```
from code1 import a
```

The import statement will differ slightly if your modules are not at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

The code showed below is based on the fact that files `code1.py` and `code2.py` are in the same directory.

### Solution 1

In this code I have changed only your `import` instruction in `code2.py`:

```
from code1 import a
b = a + 1
print(b)
```

### Solution 2

In this solution I don't have changed your `import` instruction in the file `code2.py`, but I have used the module name (`code1`) to refer to `a` variable. In this case it is used the access notation `moduleName.variableName`.
So the file `code2.py` becomes:

```
import code1
b = code1.a + 1
print(b)
```

This means that in this case `code1.py` is used as a Python module and not as a script (the difference between script and module could be the topic of an other question).

### Python namespace

In **Python terminology** the `moduleName` is the **namespace** defined by the module. By the namespace you can access to the objects content inside the module by the syntax `namespace.object`.
The interpreter creates a global namespace for any module that your program loads with the import statement.
So in the code showed by the question the variable `a` is part of the namespace `code1`.

---

**Link useful about the topic of the post**

- About namespace useful [this link of realpython](https://realpython.com/python-namespaces-scope/).
- For an example about access to an attribute of a class defined in an other module [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74196240/how-do-i-access-the-variable-inside-a-class-method-from-another-python-file)
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74326299/access-variables-from-main-program-in-python) there is an example for access to a dictionary defined in an other module