# How do I access the variable inside a class method from another python file?

Tags: python, class, selenium-webdriver, class-attributes

I have two python files `main.py` and `conftest.py`. I want to access a variable of a method of the class `Test` declared in  `main.py` from a function declared in `conftest.py`.
I have tried a bit, but I know it's wrong as I get a syntax error in the first place. Is there any way to do this?

###### main.py

```
class Test():

    def test_setup(self):
        #make new directory for downloads
        new_dir = r"D:\Selenium\Insights\timestamp}".format(timestamp=datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'))
        # print(new_dir)
        if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
            os.makedirs(new_dir)
            saved_dir=new_dir
```

###### conftest.py

```
from main import Test

def newfunc():
    dir=Test.test_setup()
    print(dir.saved_dir)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the execution of your function `newfunc()` the first instruction `dir=Test.test_setup()` raise the following error:

```
dir=Test.test_setup()
TypeError: test_setup() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

This error referred to an attempt to execute a method of a class by attribute reference but it requests an argument which is in general an instance of that class.

To solve this, and other errors present in your code, and build an  answer to your question I think that it is enough to do following steps:

- define the variable `save_dir` as an attribute of the class `Test`
- instantiate an object of the `Test` class.

In your code `saved_dir` is a local variable of the method `test_setup` so **it is not visible outside of that method**.

I show you the 2 possible correct files:

### File main.py

```
from datetime import datetime
import os

class Test():
  def __init__(self):
    self.new_dir = ""
    self.saved_dir = ""

  def test_setup(self):   
    #make new directory for downloads
    #new_dir = r"D:\Selenium\Insights\timestamp}".format(timestamp=datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'))
    timestamp=datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
    self.new_dir = "/home/frank/Selenium/Insights/timestamp/" + timestamp 
    # print(new_dir)
    if not os.path.exists(self.new_dir):
      os.makedirs(self.new_dir)
      self.saved_dir = self.new_dir
      
  def get_saved_dir(self):
    return self.saved_dir
```

**Pay attention**: don't use directly the previous code because in `main.py` I have adjusted the value of `new_dir` according to my environment (see `/home/frank/Selenium/Insights/timestamp/` instead of your `D:\Selenium\Insights\timestamp`).

### File conftest.py:

```
from main import Test

def newfunc():
    test_class = Test()
    test_class.test_setup()
    print(test_class.get_saved_dir())

newfunc()
```

If you want to access to the attribute `saved_dir` directly without the use of method `get_saved_dir()` (*not very object oriented*) the file `conftest.py` becomes:

```
from main import Test

def newfunc():
    test_class = Test()
    test_class.test_setup()
    # access directly to attribute saved_dir (not properly Object Oriented)
    print(test_class.saved_dir)

newfunc()
```

---

### Accessing the attributes of a class by reference

[This](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) is a useful link (it is included in the tutorial of official Python documentation) about the access to a variable or a method of a class.

Previous link explains how to access to an attribute of a class by reference.
If we adapt this concept to this post we can access the method `test_setup` of the class `Test`, by the following syntax:

```
f = Test.test_setup
```

If we print on the standard output the value of `f` we obtain:

```
print(f)

# this is the output
<function Test.test_setup at 0x7f93f54316a8>
```

and this means that `f` is a *valid attribute reference to a function object*. In particular I referred to the following sentence of the [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects):

> MyClass.i and MyClass.f are valid attribute references, returning an integer and a function object, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and alternatives. It worked well for me.

Answer (score 2):

Local variable `save_dir` must be declared as an attribute of the class `Test`:

```
class Test():

  def __init__(self):
    self.new_dir = ""
    self.saved_dir = ""

  def test_setup(self):
    #make new directory for downloads
    self.new_dir = r"D:\Selenium\Insights\timestamp}".format(timestamp=datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'))
    # print(self.new_dir)
    if not os.path.exists(self.new_dir):
      os.makedirs(self.new_dir)
      self.saved_dir=self.new_dir
```

Then you have to instantiate an object of the class `Test` and by this object access `save_dir`:

```
def newfunc():
    dir=Test().test_setup()
    print(dir.saved_dir)
```

Comment: Thanks, @surge10. It makes total sense while calling the variable. Appreciate the help