# Access variables from main program in python

Tags: python, variables, module

I'm new to this website, may I have some help on the following?

I have a `main.py` program that contains the dictionary `loaddict`.

I have a module outside of the main program that contains multiple functions which all of them requires the dictionary `loaddict` from the main program.

Is there a way to access the dictionary `loaddict` from multiple functions in this module without setting `loaddict` as a parameter for all of them?

The following code doesn't work, as the remaining function still does not have access to `loaddict` from the function `dgm` even with the use of keyword `global`.

```
## main program (main.py)
## user inputs data into dictionary: loaddict = {some data}

import BeamDiagram.dgm(loaddict, other parameters)
```

```
## module (BeamDiagram.py)

def dgm(loaddict, other parameters): 
    global loaddict 
    ## some calculations, this part is fine

def function1(some parameters): 
    ## calculations that requires loaddict

def function2(some parameters): 
    ## calculations that requires loaddict

def function3(some parameters): 
    ## calculations that requires loaddict
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your mistake: the import in the script `BeamDiagram.py`

In my opinion your mistake is only the `import` instruction, so in your code it is necessary only a correct `import` that is the following:

```
from main import loaddict
```

Below I show you the 2 files that I have created in my system (both files are in the same folder `/home/frank/stackoverflow`).

### main.py

```
loaddict = {'key1': 'value1'}

''' The function print the value associates to 'key1' in the dictionary loaddict 
'''
def print_dict():
    print(loaddict['key1'])
```

In `main.py` I have created the function `print_dict()` which is imported by the script `BeamDiagram.py` as it is imported the dictionary `loaddict` (see below for the code of `BeamDiagram.py`)

### BeamDiagram.py

```
'''
Module BeamDiagram.py
'''

from main import loaddict, print_dict

''' In the function the parameter 'loaddict' has been removed...
'''
def dgm(other_parameters):
    # no global keyword inside the function
    print(loaddict['key1'])

''' function1 modify loaddict value and call a function from main.py
'''
def function1(some_parameters):
    # the following instruction is able to modify the value of associated to 'key1'
    loaddict['key1'] = 'value2'
    print_dict()    # print 'value2' on standard output

dgm('other_params')
function1('some_params')
```

The script `BeamDiagram.py` calls the functions `dgm()` and `function1()` and this means that:

- it is possible the read access to `loaddict` (`dgm()`)
- it is possible the write access to `loaddict` (`function1()`)
- the modification of `key1` value is visible in `main.py`, and in effect the function `print_dict1()` prints `value2` which is the value of `key1` after that `function1()` has made the **write access** to `loaddict`

---

- A useful link is: [Python Module Variables](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_module_variables.asp).
- Useful post about module variable is: [How to create module-wide variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977362/how-to-create-module-wide-variables-in-python).